# yaml pipeline job condition throwing unrecognized value error

Tags: yaml

I have a pipeline in Azure DevOps which build my iOS application I want to separate the environments and what I am building for by jobs and conditions.  I have set up the initial parameter select:

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: Environment
    displayName: "Environment"
    type: string
    default: Dev
    values:
    - Dev
    - Live
  - name: Build
    displayName: "Build"
    type: string
    default: iPhone
    values:
    - iPhone
    - iPhoneSimulator
```

and then where I set up the different job I have added a condition:

```yaml
      - job:
        condition: and(succeeded(), eq(${{ parameters.Build }}, iPhone))
        steps:
          - checkout: none
```

When I try to run this I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. Unrecognized value: 'iPhone'. Located at position 21 within expression: and(succeeded(), eq(iPhone, iPhone)).
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`iPhone` is not a valid [literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#literals). Since [parameter expansion happens before condition evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#use-a-template-parameter-as-part-of-a-condition), you need to make sure that your condition has proper syntax after parameter expansion by enclosing string literals in single quotes:

```
and(succeeded(), eq('${{ parameters.Build }}', 'iPhone'))
```

Comment: Thank you very much.